# error when writing to a text file in python [I/O operation on closed file]

Tags: python, file, text, save, file-writing

I wanted to make a file in python and i came across a error. i have no idea why it comes up with this, i did look online but couldn't find any solutions to my problem. and i have imported random and i do have a list for enc1

```
f = open("Skins.txt",'w')
for r in range(1,1201):
   f.write(str(r))
   f.write(",")
   f.write(random.choice(enc1))
   f.write("\n")
   f.close()
```

The error:

```
    f.write(str(r))
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to close the file at end of each iteration. Move close operation out of loop block.

```
f = open("Skins.txt",'w')
for r in range(1,1201):
   f.write(str(r))
   f.write(",")
   f.write(random.choice(enc1))
   f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Or use `with` to open your file once outside the loop and use `writelines` to write the data:

```
with open("Skins.txt",'w') as f:
     f.writelines("{},{}\n".format(r, random.choice(enc1)) for r in range(1,1201))
```

Comment: perfect! silly mistake when i was indenting! i will mark answered in a bit! :D

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the file inside the loop, hence after the first iteration the file is closed, and hence trying to write to it fails with the error you are getting.

I would suggest using [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt) to open the file (so that it automatically handles closing the file for you), so that this kind of issues does not occur. Also, you do not need all those different `f.write()` statements, you cna use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and do the same in a single `.write()` .

Example -

```
with open("Skins.txt",'w') as f:
    for r in range(1,1201):
       f.write("{},{}\n".format(r, random.choice(enc1)))
```